# Nexus 10 boots into fastboot, but not into anything else

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I am stuck with what seams like a dead Nexus 10 or a stupid issue.

If the device is powered off -- And I hit `vol+` `vol-` and `pwr` -- It boots into `fastboot`.  After that, no joy.  I get black screen if I attempt to start (No Google logo even).  I get black screen when I try recovery.  I simply cannot get past fastboot.

Things I have attempted:

1. Disconnect / Reconnect Battery
2. Erased Cache
3. Finally flash-all with Manta Image (successful)

Still after all that, it boots straight to black screen.  Something is royally screwed, or I am missing something glaring .. Suggestions?